# цветной текст в richedit. Борланд с++

Tags: c++builder

Нашел способ разукрашивания текста в richedit по ключевым словам. Все работает но процесс перерисовки в случае большего размера файла и большего количества ключевых слов происходит довольно медленно. Хотел узнать если способ делать перерисовку быстрее.

```
   // структура форматирования
struct THiLt
{
    TColor FontColor;
    TFontStyles FontStyle;
};
//
struct THiLtEx // универсальная структура форматирования со списком слов/символов
{
    THiLt* Format; // указатель на объект THiLt
    TStringList* KeyWords; // список
    bool ByWords; // если TRUE, поиск будет по словам, если FALSE - по символам
};typedef THiLtEx*  pHiLtEx;
 
 // и наконец, вектор, куда можно добавлять группы
std::vector<THiLtEx*> vGroups;
 
***
// Функция HighLight для парсинга от заданной позиции до конца текста
 
void __fastcall TFEditor::HighLight(TRichEdit *REdit, int pos, bool dynamic)
{
 
     // получаем маску событий
    int eventMask = ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
    // отключаем перерисовку
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
    // запоминаем выделение
    CHARRANGE chrgSave, chrgNew;
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM) &chrgSave);
 
    int startat, toend, foundat, caretpos, slth;
 
    // сброс форматирования
    chrgNew.cpMin = pos;
    chrgNew.cpMax = -1;
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM) &chrgNew);
    REdit->SelAttributes->Color = REdit->Font->Color;
    REdit->SelAttributes->Style = REdit->Font->Style;
 
    foundat = -1;
 
    // опции поиска - по словам
    TSearchTypes sOpts = TSearchTypes();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     pHiLtEx Gr = nullptr;
     std::vector<pHiLtEx>::iterator it;
 
     TPoint cp;
     GetCaretPos(&cp);
 
    for ( it=vGroups.begin(); it < vGroups.end(); it++ )
    { // цикл по вектору
 
        Gr = *it;
 
        if (Gr->ByWords) sOpts = TSearchTypes() << stWholeWord; // опции поиска - по словам
        else sOpts = TSearchTypes(); // опции поиска - по символам
 
        // ищем по списку ключевых символов...
        for (int i=0; i<Gr->KeyWords->Count; i++)
        {
 
                    startat = pos;
                    toend = REdit->Text.Length();
 
            // если найдено следующее совпадение...
            while (0 <= (foundat = REdit->FindText(Gr->KeyWords->Strings[i], startat, toend, sOpts)))
                {
                    // выделяем текст
                chrgNew.cpMin = foundat;
                chrgNew.cpMax = foundat + Gr->KeyWords->Strings[i].Length();
                ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM) &chrgNew);
                // и применяем формат
                REdit->SelAttributes->Color =Gr->Format->FontColor;
                REdit->SelAttributes->Style =Gr->Format->FontStyle;
                if(!dynamic){  }
                // обновляем переменные для поиска
                startat += Gr->KeyWords->Strings[i].Length();
                toend = REdit->Text.Length() - startat;
                }
        }
    }
 
TRect r;//прямоугольник который будем перерисовывать
r.Right=REdit->ClientWidth;
r.Top=cp.y-30;//с небольшим запасом на всякий)
r.Bottom=cp.y+30;
 
 
 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // восстанавливаем положение каретки / выделение
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM) &chrgSave);
 
    // восстанавливаем перерисовку
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
   if(!dynamic) ::InvalidateRect(REdit->Handle, 0, true); else ::InvalidateRect(REdit->Handle, &r, true);
    // восстанавливаем маску событий
    ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, eventMask);
 
}
 
// Перегруженная функция Highlight для парсинга всего текста:
 
void __fastcall TFEditor::HighLight(TRichEdit *REdit)
{
    HighLight(REdit, 0, false); // всего и делов :)
}
 
// Функция HighlightDynamic для динамического парсинга текста при наборе:
 
void __fastcall TFEditor::HighLightDynamic(TRichEdit *REdit)
{
// сдвигаемся на 2 слова назад
    int pos = ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_FINDWORDBREAK, WB_MOVEWORDLEFT, REdit->SelStart);
 
    pos = ::SendMessage(REdit->Handle, EM_FINDWORDBREAK, WB_MOVEWORDLEFT, pos);
 
    HighLight(REdit, pos, true);
}
```